# Line Chart - CanvasJS and .jsp file

Tags: jsp, charts, canvasjs

I have personal project and I want to present a simply chart with some data. There are dates on X axis and int results on Y. I have project in Spring Boot with Hibernate (MySQL) and .jsp views and now I am trying to implement the CanvasJS.
I don't know what they did in the second loop here: https://canvasjs.com/spring-mvc-charts/line-chart/

```
<c:forEach items="${dataPointsList}" var="dataPoints" varStatus="loop"> 
    <c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoint">
        xValue = parseInt("${dataPoint.x}");
        yValue = parseFloat("${dataPoint.y}");
        dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
            x : xValue,
            y : yValue
        });     
    </c:forEach>    
</c:forEach>
```

Why they reference to dataPoints: *dps[0]* and xValue is data.point.x, not from the List value?

This is my code here:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/sugarplus/sugars/graphs")
    public String showCharts(ModelMap modelMap){
        List<Sugar> sugarList = jpaSugarService.findSugarsByDate();
        modelMap.addAttribute("sugarDataChart", sugarList);
        return "test";
    }
```

.jsp file with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css"/>
<%@    include file="header.jsp" %>
<head>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            let arr = [];
            let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                title: {
                    text: "Wykres pomiarów"
                },
                axisX: {
                    title: "Data pomiaru",
                    gridThickness: 2,
                    valueFormatString: "DD MMM"
                },
                axisY: {
                    title: "Cukier"
                },
                data: [
                    {
                        type: "line",
                        xValueType: "dateTime",
                        dataPoints: arr[0]
                    }
                ]
            });

            let xValue;
            let yValue;
            <c:forEach items="${sugarDataChart}" var="sugars" varStatus="loop">

                <c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoints">

                    xValue = "${dataPoints.x}";
                    yValue = "${dataPoints.y}";
                    arr["${loop.index}"].push({
                        x: xValue,
                        y: yValue
                    });
            </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
            chart.render();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
<%@    include file="footer.jsp" %>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi ,`dataPoints.x` means here `dataPoints` is variable which is defined in `c loop` and `x` is object type i.e : `HashMap<Object,Object>()` . You can check content of x and y at `Model` tab in above link which you have provided.

Comment: I want to update new values in jsp ,in controller I have while loop generating new values ,how to update new values in jsp ,I can't use model attribute in while loop ,please help me